# How to make pages available to public while in pending status?

Tags: 2010, publishing-page, publishing, public-website, cms

I notice that pages with pending status become unavailable for viewing to the public.
Is there a way to make sure the page is always available to the public?
By right, the previous published version of the page should stay visible to public while it is still pending.

Anyone can advise?

I am running Sharepoint 2010 as a content management system for my company's website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty much control the permissions for drafts and unpublished items using library settings:

Go to the `Pages` -> `Library Settings` -> `Versioning Settings` -> `Enable major and minor versions both.` and for -> `Draft Item security` select the following option to enable viewing of draft and pending pages:

> Select any user who can read items